# Can a Python descriptor be a persistent iterable?

Tags: python, xml-serialization, descriptor

I'm working on a lightweight class wrapper for XML data, along the lines of http://packages.python.org/dexml/api/dexml.fields.html or https://gist.github.com/485977. The classes contain an elementTree Element and have descriptors to provide property access (Apologies for the amount of code included, I thought it would be easier to grok with most of the comments left in)

```
class XPropBase(object):

    DEFAULT_TO = (lambda s, x: str(x))
    DEFAULT_FROM = (lambda s, p: p)

    def __init__(self, path, convert_from=None, convert_to = None, read_only = False, allow_missing=False):
        '''
        important bits here are convert_to and convert_from, which do the translation in and out of XML strings in derived classes...
        '''
        self.path = path
        self.convert_from = convert_from or self.DEFAULT_FROM
        self.convert_to = convert_to or self.DEFAULT_TO
        self.read_only = read_only
        self.allow_missing = allow_missing


    def _get_xml(self, instance):
        #only a an instance method for convenience...
            #intended to be overridden for different target instances
        return instance.get_element()


class XElement(XPropBase):
    '''
    Wraps an xml item whose content is contained in the text  of
    an XML tag, ie:  <tag>Content</tag>. The convert_to and convert_from methods
    will be applied to the text property of the corresponding Element 


    @note this will use the first instance of a given node path that it finds,
    so it is not guaranteed if the supplied path leads to more than one xml tag.
    '''

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):

        the_xml = self._get_xml(instance)

        if not self.path: 
            return self.convert_from(the_xml.text)        

        try:
            underlying = the_xml.find(self.path)            
            return self.convert_from(underlying.text)
        except AttributeError:
            if self.allow_missing:
                return None
            else:
                raise XMLWrapperError, "%s has no element named %s" % (instance, self.path)


    def __set__(self, instance, value, owner =None):

        if self.read_only: 
            raise XMLWrapperError('%s is a read-only property' % self.path)        

        the_xml= self._get_xml(instance)
        if not self.path:
            the_xml.text = self.convert_to(value)
            return

        try:
            underlying = self._get_xml(instance).find(self.path)
            underlying.text = self.convert_to(value)
        except AttributeError:
            if self.allow_missing:
                SubElement(self._get_xml(instance), self.path, text=self.convert_to(value))
            else:                
                raise XMLWrapperError, "%s has no element named %s" % (instance, self.path)


class XAttrib(XPropBase):
    '''
    Wraps a property in an attribute on the containing xml tag specified by path

    if the supplied attribute is not present, will raise an XMLWrapperError unless the allow_missing flag is set to True
    '''

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        try:
            res = self._get_xml(instance).attrib[self.path]      
            return self.convert_from(res)
        except KeyError:
            if self.allow_missing:
                return None
            raise XMLWrapperError, "%s has no attribute named %s" % (instance, self.path)

    def __set__(self, instance, value, owner =None):
        xml = self._get_xml(instance)
        has_element = xml.get(self.path, 'NOT_FOUND')
        if has_element == 'NOT_FOUND' and not self.allow_missing:
            raise XMLWrapperError, "%s has no attribute named %s" % (instance, self.path)
        xml.set(self.path, self.convert_to(value))

    def _get_element(self):
        return None

    def _get_attribute(self):
        return self.path

class XInstance(XPropBase):
    '''
    Represents an attribute which is mapped onto a class. The supplied class is specified in the constructor

    @note: As with XElement, this works on the first appropriately named tag it
    finds. If there are multiple path values with the same tag, it will cause
    errors.
    '''



    def __init__(self, path, cls, convert_from=None, convert_to = None, read_only = False, allow_missing=False):        
        self.cls = cls        
        XPropBase.__init__(self, path, convert_from = convert_from , convert_to = convert_to , read_only = read_only, allow_missing=allow_missing)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        sub_elem = self._get_xml(instance).find(self.path)
        if not sub_elem and not self.allow_missing:
            XMLWrapperError, "%s has no child named %s" % (instance, self.path) 
        return self.cls(sub_elem)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        my_element  = self._get_xml(instance)
        original_child = my_element.find(self.path)
        if original_child:
            my_element.remove(original_child)
        my_element.append(self._get_xml(value))


class XInstanceGroup(XInstance):
    '''
    Represents a collection of XInstances contained below a particular tag

    '''

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return [self.cls(item) for item in self._get_xml(instance).findall(self.path)]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        my_element  = self._get_xml(instance)
        for item in my_element.findall(self.path):
            my_element.remove(item)
        for each_element in map(self._get_xml, value):
            my_element.append(each_element)
```

Seems to work (though thorough testing is to come) but there is one annoying bit. The XInstanceGroup descriptor handles cases like this:

```
<Object name="dummy">
    <Child name="kid2" blah="dee blah"/>
    <Child name="kid2" blah="zey"/>
</Object>

class Kid(XMLData):
    Name = XAttribute("name")
    Blah = XAttribute("blah")

class DummyWrapper(XMLData):
    Name = XAttribute("name")
    Kids = XInstanceGroup('Child', Kid)
```

So if you as for a DummyWrapper for it's kids you get a list of Kid objects. However I'm unhappy about the process of updating that list:

```
 #this works
 kids = Dummy_example.Kids
 kids.append(Kid (name = 'marky mark', blah='funky_fresh'))
 Dummy_example.Kids = kids

 #this doesn't
 Dummy_example.Kids.append(Kid(name = 'joey fatone', blah = 'indeed!'))
```

necessitated by the fact that Dummy.Kids is really a function that returns a group, not a persistent list object stored as a member field.

Now for the question: Is there a way to do this using descriptors? It seems like the hurdle is that the descriptor instance can't persist the data - it only knows about the instance when it's called. I  dislike the idea of somehow injecting the storage into the instances from the descriptor  (if nothing else, it increases coupling unpleasantly).  The obvious Googling has not helped so far.